# The variable from AJAX is not visible in the function

Tags: php, ajax

I want to write a simple pagination in PHP & JS using an AJAX request. For this purpose, when I receive onclick, I send the page using POST to the debug.php file, which has the following content.

If the display of a variable in PHP outside the function displays what I want, then already inside the function, binding it as a parameter displays me an empty array. The SQL query is correct, the code on the AJAX side also. Somewhere in the .php file is an error, but I have no idea where.

```
include "../config.php";

$page = $_POST["page"];

function getRef($dbh, $page) {

    $uid = 3;

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `ref` = :uid LIMIT :page, 1");
    $stmt->bindParam(":uid", $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(":page", $page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $result;

}

print_r(getRef($dbh, $page));
```

Comment: Dumb question, have you checked $dbh is valid in the function? Where is the database connection  set up?

Comment: Yes, everything is fine here. If I do not bind the parameter in the query, I insert ".$_POST[" page "]." the query works, but it's a dangerous solution.

Comment: What is the value of $page? If you simply replace page: with, say, 0 in the query does it work? Do you mean to only get one row?

Comment: The value of $ page to the number of clicks on the JS side sent to the post php. I will put children there, eg 10 - it will work.